# How to apply augmentations to only new data created by oversampling in PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

So I have a train dataset (created with torch.utils.data.random_split) of RGB images size 150x150 with 7 total classes. There is a class imbalance present, that I fixed with a weighted sampler. However, I also wanted to add image augmentations to the new data I created to avoid overfitting as their would be duplicate images otherwise. Here is what I have so far:

```py
# define data augmentation transforms for training set
transform_train = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
    transforms.RandomResizedCrop(size=150, scale=(0.8, 1.0)),
    transforms.ColorJitter(brightness=0.4, contrast=0.4, saturation=0.4),
    transforms.RandomRotation(degrees=15),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
])

# get the indices of examples in each class in the training set
class_indices = [[] for _ in range(7)]
for i in range(len(train_dataset)):
    _, label = train_dataset[i]
    class_indices[label].append(i)

# calculate the number of examples to sample from each class
max_class_size = max([len(class_indices[c]) for c in range(7)])
class_weights = [max_class_size / len(class_indices[c]) for c in range(7)]
num_samples = [int(class_weights[c] * len(class_indices[c])) for c in range(7)]

# create a WeightedRandomSampler to oversample the training set
sampler = data.WeightedRandomSampler(weights=class_weights, num_samples=sum(num_samples), replacement=True)
train_loader = data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=64, sampler=sampler)

# create new training set with oversampled examples
oversampled_train_dataset = data.Subset(train_dataset, indices=list(sampler))
oversampled_train_dataset.transform = transform_train
```

As you can see, currently I apply the transforms to the entire train data at the end, which isn't what I want. The result of the current code, is that I get a train accuracy of 1.0 on epoch 1! while validation accuracy hovers around 0.25. It does not improve/change either as epochs progress. Without oversampling the final train accuracy is about 0.84 while validation accuracy is about 0.71.

A side note, there are about 20000 images in the trainset before oversampling so the for loop takes a while to run, if there are optimizations I can make, I would appreciate suggestions. thanks

Answer (score 1):

My idea is you can create two `DataLoader`s, and then concatenate them during training. Here's the idea:

```py
# No Augmentation
transform_train = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(),
])

# With Augmentation
transform_train_subset = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
    transforms.RandomResizedCrop(size=150, scale=(0.8, 1.0)),
    transforms.ColorJitter(brightness=0.4, contrast=0.4, saturation=0.4),
    transforms.RandomRotation(degrees=15),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
])

# create a WeightedRandomSampler to oversample the training set
sampler = data.WeightedRandomSampler(weights=class_weights, num_samples=sum(num_samples), replacement=True)
train_loader = data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=64, sampler=sampler)

# create new training set with oversampled examples
oversampled_train_dataset = data.Subset(train_dataset, indices=list(sampler))

# Sampling the subset
oversampled_train_dataset.transform = transform_train_subset
subset_train_loader = train_loader = data.DataLoader(oversampled_train_dataset, batch_size=64, sampler=sampler)

for i, (x_full, y_full), (x_subset, y_subset) in enumerate(zip(train_loader, subset_train_loader)):
    imgs = torch.cat((x_full, x_subset), dim=0)
    labels = torch.cat((y_full, y_subset), dim=0)
    # Your training code here
```

Since I do not have your data, it is hard to test.

Comment: I see, thank you for the suggestion. How would the train loop work exactly with the concatenation? My current train loop looks like this (mind the formatting): 

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for imgs, labels in iter(train_loader):
      if torch.cuda.is_available():
        imgs = imgs.cuda()
        labels = labels.cuda()  
      out = model(imgs)             
      loss = criterion(out, labels) 
      loss.backward()               
      optimizer.step()              
      optimizer.zero_grad()

Comment: You can use `imgs = torch.cat((x_full, x_subset), dim=0)` and `labels = torch.cat((y_full, y_subset), dim=0)` to concatenate the data, and they will behave just like a single dataloader. I have added it to the answer.

Comment: Running this gives me the following error: "not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)"